# Proving that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(a\check{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}+\left(1-a\right)\hat{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)^{\alpha}\geq 1$

Tags: inequality

I'd like to show that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \tilde q_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(a\check{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}+\left(1-a\right)\hat{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)^{\alpha}\geq 1,
$$

given that $a,\alpha,\check{q}_i,\hat{q}_i\in\left[0,1\right]$ and that $\sum_{i=1}^n\check q=\sum_{i=1}^n\hat q=1$.

If $\alpha=1$, $\sum_{i=1}^n\tilde q=1$, and I believe that this sum is decreasing in $\alpha$. However, I'm not able to establish the sign of the derivative. This derivative is

$$ 
\frac{d \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tilde q_{i}}{d \alpha}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\tilde q_{i}\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(-\frac{a \check{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\ln \check{q}_{i}+\left(1-a\right) \hat{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\ln \hat{q}_{i}}{\tilde{q}_i^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}+\ln \tilde{q}_{i}\right),
$$

and, as $\check{q}_i,\hat{q}_i\in\left[0,1\right]$ (and, therefore, $\tilde q_i\in\left[0,1\right])$, the first summand in the parenthesis is positive and the second is negative.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative can be written as

$$ 
\frac{d \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tilde q_{i}}{d \alpha}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\tilde q_{i}^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}}\left(-a \check{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\ln \check{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}-\left(1-a\right) \hat{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\ln \hat{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}+\tilde{q}_i^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\ln \tilde{q}_{i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)<0,
$$

where the inequality follows from $f(x)=x\ln x$ being a convex function.